# How to lappy() over selective columns? - R

Tags: r, lapply

I am a novice R programmer. I am wondering how to lappy over a dataframe but avoiding certain columns.

```
# Some dummy dataframe
df <- data.frame(
         grp = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
         trial = as.factor(c(1,1,2,2)),
         mean = as.factor(c(44,33,22,11)),
         sd = as.factor(c(3,4,1,.5)))

df <- lapply(df, function (x) {as.numeric(as.character(x))})
```

However, the method I used introduces NAs by coercion.

Would there to selectively (or deselectively) `lapply` over the dataframe while maintaining the integrity of the dataframe?

In other words, would there be a way to convert only mean and sd to numerics?  (In general form)

Thank you

Comment: `library(tidyverse); df %>% mutate_at(2:4, parse_number)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
df[,3:4] <- lapply(df[,3:4], function (x) {as.numeric(as.character(x))})
```

You are simply passing function to the specified columns. You can also provide a condition to select subset of your columns, something like excluding the ones you don't want to cast.

```
col = names(df)[names(df)!=c("grp","trial")]
df[,col] <- lapply(df[,col], function (x) {as.numeric(as.character(x))})
```

Comment: ahh ok. Would it matter if the columns are weirdly placed?

Comment: Just select any columns you want, for example df[,c(2,4)] if those are the once needing typecast.

Comment: You are welcome. You can also do the following: `df[,c("mean","sd")] <- lapply(df[,c("mean","sd")], function (x) {as.numeric(as.character(x))})` if that seems easier for readability purposes.

Comment: Would you be able to do an except-like command? `df[c("grp","trial"),] <- lapply(df[c("grp","trial"),], function (x) {as.numeric(as.character(x))})`

Comment: The reason I preferred to answer using the `range` syntax was its usefulness. Let's say you have 100 columns, and you want to convert 92 such columns to numeric, you can do so easily by using their indices: `c(1,2,11:100)`. You can write any excluding conditions, but they should not be on column names.

Comment: Thank you for your help that makes more sense

Answer (score 1):

Well as you might have guessed, there are many ways.  Since you seem to be doing in place substitution, actually, a for loop would be suitable.

```
df <- data.frame(
         grp = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
         trial = as.factor(c(1,1,2,2)),
         mean = as.factor(c(44,33,22,11)),
         sd = as.factor(c(3,4,1,.5)))

my_cols <- c("trial", "mean", "sd")
for(mc in my_cols) {
    df[[mc]] <- as.numeric(as.character(df[[mc]]))
}
```

Comment: That would make sense. Would there be a way to say `do this over all columns except x`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert selectively by column names:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate_if(names(.) %in% c("mean", "sd"), 
            function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```